# How to hide error messages in 7Zip command line?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, extract, 7zip, winrar

`-inul` command prevents error-box from coming up in WinRar command line. Is there any equivalent command for 7Gz.exe?

Answer (score 2):

`7-Zip` writes all its messages to `stdout`, including error and warning messages. This means you can collect all the output from it by redirecting stdout it to a file.

A command like the following will redirect all output (including from stderr) to Log.txt:

```
7za a Test.7z *.* >Log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: This is not hiding the error-box. I am using GUI of 7zip, i.e, 7Gz.exe , and it brings an error-box saying 'Wrong password?' I want to prevent this dialog box from coming.

Comment: Redirecting the output to NUL also does the job.. But those tricks work for `7z.exe` not for `7zG.exe` .. Please tell if there is a way to hide message of 7zG.exe